# Change datatype of a date partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date partitioned table with around 400 partitions.
Unfortunately one of the columns datatypes has changed and should be changed from INT to STR.

I can change the datatype as follows:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(change_var AS STRING) change_var
    <rest of columns>
FROM dataset.table_name
```

and overwrite the table, but the date partitioning is then lost.

Is there any way to keep the partitioning and change a columns datatype?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.
Export table by partition. I created a simple library to achieve it. https://github.com/rdtr/bq-partition-porter
Then create a new table with a correct type and load data into the new table again, by partition. Be careful about the quota (1000 exports per day). 400 should be okay.

Option 2.
By using Cloud Dataflow, you can export a whole table then use DynamicDestination to import data into BQ by partition. If a number of partitions are too many, this would suffice the requirement.

I expect `bq load` command to have some way to specify a partition key field name (since it's already described in `bq load help`). Until then, you need to follow either of these options.